# How to add Font Awesome icon (fa fa icon) in @Html.ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn- 
     warning fa fa-neuter" })

Comment: What is happening to make that not work for you? What does it actually do?

Comment: I need html <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a> to Razer view.

Answer (score 2):

`Html.ActionLink()` doesn't support complex links and have only plain text support.

You should use.

```
<a href="@Url.Action(...)"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> </a>
```

Comment: Hi @chandra , you may accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Accept_suggested_company", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary btn-def fa fa-save" })
```

You should only include it inside the class

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I am using this syntax in a List view. You can modify it. Use something like this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("", "Edit", new { /*id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new{@class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-def fa fa-pencil"})
```

pardon me, I haven't used the primary key field here but I will add it later.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("action name", "controller name", new { /*id=item.PrimaryKey */})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.